# Error taking address of temporary in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, list, iterator

The code below compiled successfully on Visual Studio 2010.
However, when I compile it on Linux Eclipse, I am getting an error:

../src/test.cpp:23:27: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

```
MyNode *p1 = &(MyNode)*itr;
```

Why is that? What must I change?

The code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

typedef struct MyNode_
{
    int abc;
}MyNode;

int main() {

    list<MyNode> myList;
    list<MyNode>::iterator itr;

    for(itr=myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); ++itr)
    {
        MyNode *p1 = &(MyNode)*itr; //this line cause compilation error in Eclipse

        printf("abc = %d", p1->abc);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with taking the address of a temporary  is it is gone at the end of the line leaving the pointer pointing at Crom only knows what. Sounds like the VS2010 version may have an undetected bout of Undefined Behaviouritiis.

Comment: Thank you. How can I change the code if I want to access the item the iterator is pointing to? I have tried all sorts of casting, with and without *, & and so on. But I haven't been able to find a way to do that.

Comment: `printf("abc = %d", itr->abc);`  by itself ought to do the job.

Comment: Cheers, this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must do that, then do this instead:

```
MyNode copy = *itr;
MyNode *p1 = &copy;
```

As a comment said, attempting to take address of a temporary does not work because temporaries do not have valid memory address after the line they used in.

Comment: It works for this case, but remember that you are operating on a copy, so  `p1->abc = 42` does not change the original that's still in the list.

Answer (score 3):

The path of least resistance is to not use a pointer at all:

```
printf("abc = %d", itr->abc);
```

If you really do need the address of the `MyNode` represented by `itr`, use `&*itr`.

Explanation:

`itr` is a `std::list<MyNode>::iterator`. You can get a reference to the `MyNode` it represents with the `*` operator (`*itr`). No cast is required because the result is already a `MyNode`. From this reference you can get the address of the referenced `MyNode` (`&*itr`).  Putting this all together you get

```
MyNode *p1 = &*itr;
printf("abc = %d", p1->abc);
```

Answer (score 1):

[[expr.static.cast] p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#1.sentence-2) states:

> If T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, the result is an lvalue; if T is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is an xvalue; otherwise, the result is a prvalue.

In this case, you aren't casting to a reference type, and therefore, the expression is a prvalue. Now, looking at [[expr.urnary.op] p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1.sentence-1):

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points.

The expression `(MyNode)*itr` is a prvalue, and therefore, it is ill-formed.

Comment: Great breakdown odf what went wrong. Wish I'd done this. +1, but to finish off the answer, you should add a solution.